# How can i access recently received text message's number in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create an application in which I just want to get the recently received sms's sender information(phone number,date) and I want to send a reply message to that particular number.

I tried this code, how can I get the recently received SMS's sender information?

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String string = "";
String phone = "";

if (bundle != null)
{
    //---receive the SMS message--
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]); 
        phone = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();  // Here you can get the phone number of SMS sender.
        string += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString(); // Here you can get the message body.
      }
}
```

Is there anyway to get the message sender number without extending broadcast receiver?Anyway to acces from the message log?

Comment: @Hardik in which should i extend broadcast reciever ?

Comment: Why don't you want to extend `BroadcastReceiver`? It's possible to read messages from the inbox (via `ContentProvider`) [BUT not on every device](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example step by step:

[SMS Messaging in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

Contains both receiving and replying to an sms, also includes full code! Receiving SMS is via `Broadcast Receiver`

---

> Is there anyway to get the message sender number without extending
>   broadcast receiver?Anyway to access from the message log?

You can access existing sms db via `Content Providers` but the message get there after the broadcast receiver and its more advances to "watch" when a new message is written in android database.

---

> how can I get the recently received SMS's sender information?

The answer this line:

```
phone = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();  // Here you can get the phone number of SMS sender.
```

the number is the given number at simulator OR the sender "number" given by your network provider, it can also be text.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will give you the numbers of the received text messages.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    int i =0;
    String[] number = new String[cursor.getCount()];  
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        number[i] = (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")); 
        i++;                         
        }
    }
```

To get the the number of most recently received text message, you can access

```
   String mostRecentNumber = number[0];
```